# Can "some" be a noun and a subject?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, syntactic-analysis

What is the noun in this sentence:

> Some of our greatest innovations were launched during tough times.

I know that *of our greatest innovations* is a prepositional phrase and as such cannot contain the subject of the sentence. *Some* just doesn't strike me as a noun—or is it?

If it is, what is the easy way to recognize these type of nouns?

Comment: Some would say it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full subject is ***some*** of our greatest innovations. The head of the noun phrase is *some*, which is an adjective used as a noun with a plural meaning. Most adjectives can be used as nouns in certain situations: *some like it hot; red is ugly; the weak will perish; the lowest of the low*, etc. If an adjective is modified by a prepositonal phrase, it is usually used as a noun.

Comment: "The weak will perish" The - Adjective; weak - Noun; will perish - verbal phrase. Is this correct?

Comment: @kayfun: *The* is an article. Even though you could say they function much like adjectives, articles are not normally called that. *Weak* is an adjective used as a noun.

Comment: @kayfun This use of an adjective as a noun is sometime called a "[substantive adjective](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substantive_adjective)".

Comment: _Some_ is not an adjective, nor a noun, nor a pronoun. _Some_ is a [***Quantifier***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification). Quantifiers are a type of **Determiner**, like articles and demonstratives. Specifically, _some_ is an English **Existential** quantifier, contrasting with the English Universal quantifiers _every, all,_ and _each_. If your list of Parts Of Speech doesn't have Quantifier or Determiner on it, you're not playing with a full deck. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnLawler: You can't say it "is" not something unless you deny that there are several possible models to categorise words. I find quantifier a useful concept in general, but less so in this case, because it tells you nothing about whether or not—nor why (not)—it can function like a noun, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Three of our greatest innovations were launched during tough times. Quantifier.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Sure, but what does that explain? *The beginnings of our greatest innovations too shape during tough times.* Not a quantifier...but so what? In both cases, there is a word that functions as a noun and the head of the subject; that's what explains the pattern, isn't it?

Comment: We're into a debate about how word classes are / ought to be defined here. I believe that it often, and would include this case, doesn't make sense to classify without reference to semantics. In 'some of X' and 'three of X' there is an obvious quantifying going on, a restriction of the referent (here of the subject) to some subset of the many-membered set X. Not so with 'the beginnings of X'. I'd just consider 'Three of X' as a quantified noun group...

Comment: With 'Red is ugly', 'Some like it hot', 'Five go to Finniston Farm', 'These will work'... I've got to revert to distributional prioritising and say they're nouns (some might include pronouns) formed by drafting adjectives or determiners into the role. And I understand why John Lawler downplays POS identifying.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: My question is, how does the category *quantifier* help to explain the construction in the OP? I'm not saying it does not, but it isn't clear to me. The dichotomy *adjective* in the broad sense versus *noun* does help, as in my example. You can say they "are nouns", I said they are "used as nouns". Why do you disapprove of my wording, and how is it at all different? I'm sure there has to be more behind your and Lawler's objections than a word game.

Comment: Word classes are determined (for a given word in context) not _just_ from a consideration of [simplifying some analyses of] which constructions they enter: Walter Bisang, University of Mainz: 'Prerequisites for distinguishing word classes' (sorry I can't link):
- Semantic criteria
- Pragmatic criteria / criteria of discourse function
- Formal criteria
- Distinction between lexical and syntactic levels of analysis. Sometimes, there are real problems on deciding: three _plus_ four; his slowly _painting_ the scene; pavilions _galore_. 'Some of' in 'Some of our ...' is quantifying.......

Comment: ....... (not all of our ...). The noun _innovations_ is being premodified in OP's example, initially restricted to _our_ innovations, then further to _our greatest_ innovations, and then a subset of these is specified. Not regarding _some_ here as a noun, but rather _some of_ as a determiner, causes me fewer problems. With _Some were launched during peacetime_, not regarding 'some' as a noun would cause me more problems.